# Interlacing text from multiple files based on contents of line

Tags: optimization, io, text-processing

I'm trying to take N files, which, incidentally, are all syslog log files, and interlace them based on the timestamp which is the first part of the line. I can do this naively but I fear that my approach will not scale well with any more than just a handful of these files.

So let's say I just have two files, `1.log` and `2.log`. `1.log` looks like this:

```
2016-04-06T21:13:23.655446+00:00 foo 1
2016-04-06T21:13:24.384521+00:00 bar 1
```

and `2.log` looks like this:

```
2016-04-06T21:13:24.372946+00:00 foo 2
2016-04-06T21:13:24.373171+00:00 bar 2
```

Given that example, I would want the output to be:

```
2016-04-06T21:13:23.655446+00:00 foo 1
2016-04-06T21:13:24.372946+00:00 foo 2
2016-04-06T21:13:24.373171+00:00 bar 2
2016-04-06T21:13:24.384521+00:00 bar 1
```

As that would be the lines of the files, combined, and sorted by the timestamp with which each line begins.

We can assume that each file is internally sorted before the program is run. (If it isn't, rsyslog and I have some talking to do.)

So quite naively I could write something like this, ignoring memory concerns and whatnot:

```
interlaced_lines = []
first_lines = [[f.readline(), f] for f in files]
while first_lines:
    first_lines.sort()
    oldest_line, f = first_lines[0]
    while oldest_line and (len(first_lines) == 1 or (first_lines[1][0] and oldest_line < first_lines[1][0])):
        interlaced_lines.append(oldest_line)
        oldest_line = f.readline()
    if oldest_line:
        first_lines[0][0] = oldest_line
    else:
        first_lines = first_lines[1:]
```

I fear that this might be quite slow, reading line by line like this. However, I'm not sure how else to do it. Can I perform this task faster with a different algorithm or through parallelization? I am largely indifferent to which languages and tools to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, since each file is internally presorted, I can get pretty far with [`sort --merge`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html). With over 2GB of logs it sorted them in 15 seconds. Using my example:

```
% sort --merge 1.log 2.log
2016-04-06T21:13:23.655446+00:00 foo 1
2016-04-06T21:13:24.372946+00:00 foo 2
2016-04-06T21:13:24.373171+00:00 bar 2
2016-04-06T21:13:24.384521+00:00 bar 1
```